# Beaglebone black, DLP2000evm cape problem with mono(c#)

Tags: c#, mono, debian, beagleboneblack

I am using this image (bone-debian-9.5-lxqt-armhf-2018-10-07-4gb) in my beaglebone black, and also i use DLPDLC2000 EVM projector as a cape.

recently i  followed this link (https://www.ofitselfso.com/Beagle/InstallingMonoOnTheBeagleboneBlack.php)  and install mono in my beaglebone.

i installed mono and then test it with the sample(hello word.exe and another .exe file which i made it in my laptop) and the beaglebone and DLP workperfectly.

the problem is: after restart the beaglebone black, i can see the default screen of dlp but then the dlp have no any lights, I can just see (-) in north right corner and it just blinking

please let me know , what is the problem?

thanks